# Allow to access by derived class, but not allowed to override

Tags: c++, inheritance

I need to write a member function in base class allow to access by derived class. but not allowed to override.

Is this possible?

Comment: This is known as `final` or `sealed` (virtual) methods in most OO-enabled languages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++11, you can use the `final` specifier to disallow overriding.

[Explicit overrides and final in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Explicit_overrides_and_final)

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with a `virtual` method, you can use the `final` special identifier in C++11.

```
class A
{
  virtual void foo() const final;
};
```

This will prevent either overriding or name hiding, depending on the context.

Comment: I cannot define member function like this in g++ `‘final’ does not name a type` what can be the issue? my compiler `gcc version 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2) (GCC)`

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya For C++ support you need to compile with -std=c++0x, but it seems this is only implemented from GCC 4.7 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you don't declare it `virtual` it'll be impossible to override it.

Pre C++11, there are compiler extensions if the method is `virtual`. For example, MSVS provides the `sealed` keyword.

Comment: If you don't declare it virtual, the subclass will hide the method instead of overriding it, which could be even worse.

Comment: @KennyTM you're assuming a method with the same name exists inside the derived class.

Comment: As I know possible to override without virtual.(traditional inheritance). but cannot access by base class pointers. am i right?

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya if a method is not virtual, it's not called overriding, but hiding. In which case, `final` and `sealed` can't prevent it from being hidden.

Comment: @KennyTM I still don't see what's wrong with treating both cases - virtual & non-virtual. All other answers assume the method is virtual - whereas the previous comment from the op suggest that it's not.